# polynomial ADT class

Tags: c++

I have trouble understanding use of high level ADT in a polynomial class. What i was given is

```
typedef struct term{
  double coef; 
  unsigned deg; 
  struct term * next;
}term_t;
typedef struct term * Term;
typedef struct term * Poly;
```

So this is said to be low level ADT, but i have to use high level ADT which means that I have to make a class. What I am starting doing is

```
class Polynomial{
private:
    typedef struct term{
        double coef;
        unsigned deg;
        struct term * next;
    }term_t;
    typedef struct term *Term;
    typedef struct term *Poly;
public:
    Polynomial(); //Constructor
    ~Polynomial(); //Destructor     
}
```

My problem is an understating the change of low level to ADT to high level ADT. Should the function be private but then accessed through a public functions? Is this basically like a polynomial linked list polynomial class? Is my start good? So term and poly will be a pointers to the coef and deg?

Comment: The "abstract" in abstract data type usually means users get a clean interface to construct instances and operate on them, without having to muck with pointers and memory allocation themselves. Ideally, it wouldn't show that its actual implementation is a linked list or anything else, so you can switch to a better implementation once the need arises, without changing client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ADT is data along with a collection of operations that you can perform on that data.
A low level or "C" ADT will see it implemented as a collection of functions that receive a **handle** of some sort to the data, along with other required parameters, and do the operation they represent.

In C++, however, things become more simple because those functions that represent operations can be bound to the data itself, via a class defintion.

Now, in your example, let us think about the sort of operation that can be performed on a polynomial; Let's try addition:

In C you'd define a function like this:

```
Poly poly_add (Poly p1, Polyp2)
{
/*addition code be here*/
}
```

How would we do it in C++?! Well, we want the method to be bound to the object, so we do something like this:

```
class Polynomial
{
  ....
public:
  Polynomial add(Polynomial& p2)
  {
    // addition code be here
  }
};
```

This will be called like this `p3 = p1.add(p2)`.

So to answer your question, your global methods that belong to the class can operate on the "Low Level" struct directly, and that's where you'd want to put that code.

You should also note the `Poly` and `Term` aren't pointers, but types. They are both the type of pointer that points to a `term_t` struct.

Naturally there is a lot of room for imporvment (i.e. we can make the binary operations friend functions, and even better, overloaded operators).

Comment: why do i need Poly and Term for? also is my implementation of the class right?

Comment: You don't really need both Poly and Term, it's just easier to mask a complex type with a new name.
Your implementation is syntactically correct, but it's incomplete.
Until you add some code showing how you tried to implement an operation, I can't say how good it is.

Comment: how would you create constructor? I have trouble understanding what points to what

Answer (score 0):

The way to think about Abstract Data Types is that the data is defined by what it does (its signature) and not what it consists of.  So really, your implementation is not automatically high level or low level just because you used a class; it's high level or low level if:

1. The user need not muck about with low level operations to use it.
2. The user uses the class solely in terms of its interface (black box).

When designing your class, your should put yourself in the shoes of a user who does not know or want to know anything about the implementation.  To the user, the class is just something on which they call methods and it gets the job done.  How it's done is a mystery.

Let that be your guiding principle.  The implementation details then are the things you use to make them happen, and since they are not exposed to the user, they don't have anything to do with the ADT.  The ADT is in the interface.

A more concrete test you can apply is to try to use it yourself and see how high level is.  Write a separate program to use polynomials, instantiate the class, use it, then ask yourself whether it's high level enough.  Revise as necessary until you get the right interface.